# Syntaxic error with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, toggle

I try to queue 2 animations using jQuery `.toggle()` and `.animate()` functions, and it returns a syntax error, like if I had forgotten a `}`...

But I can't see where, everything seems ok to me...
Anybody has any clue?? Or maybe a better way to do what I'm trying o do? I try to make one span going up and and down alternatively.

Here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $('body').prepend('<div id="vamos-abajo"><span></span></div>');
        $('#vamos-abajo span').toggle(function(){
            $(this).animate({top:"10px";}, 250);
        },function(){
            $(this).animate({top:"0px";}, 500);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please add some trace of the error.

Comment: The syntaxic problem has been solved by @Nosfera2, it was actually the semicolons...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the semicolons(;) in your animate.  That part would need to look like this:

```
 $(this).animate({top:"10px"}, 250);
```

Or, if you are going to animate multiple CSS properties at once, you can use a comma

```
 $(this).animate({top:"10px", left:"15px"}, 250);
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems that I have passed too much time doing CSS... But the animation still doesn't work... Do you have an idea?